# Is it possible to change a custom trait from a parent trait collection and observe the changes to all view controllers?

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to create a custom trait object and put it into the `UITraitCollection` class using some new APIs in iOS 17. As an example, what I want to do is create multiple app theme traits, put them into the trait collection class, and make all of the current available `UIViewController` objects to observe the theme trait changes. I'm aware that in iOS 17, UIKit has a new method to override a trait definition by mutating the new `traitOverrides` property. But based on the [WWDC23 video session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10057/), Apple told us to use this property only for specific view controllers or views and all of its children/subviews. So the changes don't reflect to all of the view controllers that are currently available in memory. Here's what I did so far:

Creating a new custom `UITraitDefinition`:

```
enum ThemeTraitType: Int {
    case light
    case dark
    case monochrome
}

struct ThemeTrait: UITraitDefinition {
    typealias Value = ThemeTraitType
    
    static let defaultValue: ThemeTraitType = .light
    static var name: String = "Theme"
    static var affectsColorAppearance: Bool = true
}
```

Added it into the `UITraitCollection` class using extensions:

```
extension UITraitCollection {
    var currentTheme: ThemeTraitType { self[ThemeTrait.self] }
}

extension UIMutableTraits {
    var currentTheme: ThemeTraitType {
        get { self[ThemeTrait.self] }
        set { self[ThemeTrait.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Register the trait changes observer:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        registerForTraitChanges([ThemeTrait.self], handler: { (self: Self, previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection) in
            // Do something here...
        })
    }

}
```

Change the `currentTheme` trait using the new `traitOverrides` property:

```
traitOverrides.currentTheme = .dark
```

This works as expected for the view controller where I change the trait from. But let's say I'm using a `UINavigationController` and have 5 view controllers inside the navigation controller and I change the trait inside the last view controller (which is the 5th view controller inside the stack), when I go back to the previous view controller, the trait changes doesn't reflect on all of the previous view controllers. What I want to do is the changes I've made inside any view controllers will also reflect to all of the available view controllers that currently exist in memory. Is this possible to implement? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIKit trait system is a mechanism to propagate data through the tree structure of your app's hierarchy. You can see illustrations of the trait hierarchy in the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10057/) you mentioned — but the general idea is that it starts at each `UIWindowScene`, and includes all `UIWindow` instances that are connected to that window scene, and then within each window it is based on the `UIView` instances in the view hierarchy. Any `UIViewController` whose `view` has been added to the view hierarchy (meaning `view.window != nil`) is a part of the trait hierarchy.

However, an object (e.g. view, view controller, etc) that has been created and is in-memory is not necessarily a part of the trait hierarchy at any point in time. For example, a view or view controller that was newly created which hasn't been added into the hierarchy yet (e.g. adding the view using `addSubview`, or by presenting the view controller, etc) is not a part of the trait hierarchy yet. Similarly, if a view controller has its view removed from the hierarchy (e.g. a presentation is dismissed, or another view controller is pushed on a navigation stack causing the previous view controller to disappear), then that view controller is no longer a part of the trait hierarchy until its view gets put back into the hierarchy later (if ever).

Data only flows through the trait system to objects that are a part of the trait hierarchy. This is very important, as the exact values received by any given object is dependent on *where* it appears within that hierarchy, because traits are inherited from parent to child. It's impossible to know with certainty which trait values an object should receive, if its parent is not known because it hasn't been added to the hierarchy yet.

Therefore, the trait system is not designed to propagate values to the trait collection of objects that aren't in the hierarchy. If/when the object is added to the hierarchy later on, it will receive updated trait values at that time.

The most important question you should ask yourself here is this: why do you need objects that are not in the hierarchy to receive this data? By definition, an object that is not a part of the hierarchy cannot be visible to the user, and thus it should not need to update until some point in the future if/when it gets added to the hierarchy (at which point it will receive updated trait values). Any objects that have incorrect or stale trait values will always get a chance to update when they get put into the hierarchy, before the user can see them.

If you truly need to broadcast the same information to all objects in memory, then the trait system is probably not the right choice of infrastructure to use for that use case. Instead, you might consider something like posting a notification via notification center.

Comment: I didn't expect to get a response from the person that was in the video I was watching. Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @smileyborg thank you for the great answer! Just wanted to clarify one thing: are traits propagated when an object is added to the hierarchy? E.g. in an app theming example, if you have a view that is registered for trait updates on your custom theme trait, when it is added to a parent view that has the trait set, does the view get that value? Or does it need to wait for the next change to get the update? In real life terms: if you add a subview to a "themed" parent, is there a way to pick up the theme or does the trait need to be overridden after the child is added?

Comment: @Amja An object's traits are updated as soon as it is added to the hierarchy. Newly created objects, or ones that have been removed from the hierarchy, have either predicted or last-known trait values in their trait collection, but those values will be "frozen" until the object goes into the hierarchy. So the act of adding an object to the hierarchy will cause any trait updates (and change callbacks) for that object to occur; you don't need to manually cause a trait change on an ancestor afterwards just to propagate values to the new object(s) in the hierarchy.

Comment: @smileyborg makes sense ❤️ I am sadly not seeing the trait update work correctly when added to the hierarchy.

E.g. for a VC:
- In viewDidAppear: register a button for trait changes then add it to the VC's hierarchy.
- If I set the VC's trait override at the top of viewDidAppear, the button's callback runs when it gets added as a subview.
- But if I apply the override before the VC is presented, the callback never runs!

I thought that just registering a view for trait changes and then adding it to a VC with trait overrides was enough to trigger the trait change callback. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Amja "if I apply the override before the VC is presented, the callback never runs" That sounds to me like your VC and its view haven't been added to the hierarchy yet, then. So even if you add the button to that VC's view, if the VC's view still has a nil window, then neither the VC, its view, or the button will receive any trait updates yet as they are all out of the hierarchy. Once the VC is presented, then that will cause everything to get put into the hierarchy, and that's the point where you will see the updates occur.